# Unable to start an activity from fragment

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments

I have an imageView in a fragment. On imageView click I want to start an activity. Below is my code showing null pointer exception.

```
     public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {
  //  public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    Context con=getActivity();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();                           
        ImageView shadow_img=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shadow_img);
        ImageView img=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Article.class);

                 getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
               });
        shadow_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.featured_shadow);

        new ImageLoadTask(args.getString("img_url"),(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img),con).execute(null, null);
        return rootView;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code run fine, try litlle changes.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        ViewGroup rootView = null;
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layname, container, false);

        Button btnSec = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSec);
        btnSec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent iz = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
             startActivity(iz)
```